# iTerm2 & MacVim: Why light white shadow overlays the screen?

Tags: vim, macvim, iterm2, iterm

When a file is opened within iTerm using vim, light white shadow overlays the entire screen making the text unreadable. 
How can I get this fixed?

Open within iTerm:
[image]

Open in vim app:[image]

Comment: Play around with iTerm's colour settings. It's how I fixed mine. Also this question would suit the [Vi & Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) better.

Answer (score -1):

It's related to the theme that you chose in iTerm2. 
As alex said, feel free to play around with the iTerm2' color settings.
[image]